# Rufus-scheduler : How do I enforce a certain amount of jobs running at any given time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rufus-scheduler

Here's some sample code from a file in my config/initializers directory :

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton(:max_work_threads => 20)

.
.

job_id = scheduler.every '5s' do
  # do stuff that may take 1 minute or 50 minutes
  method_call_one
  log "method one finished"
  method_call_two
  log "method two finished"
  method_call_three
  log "method three finished, all done!"
end
```

Yet, as execution proceeds, I discover that more than 20 such jobs are running at any given time (the last logging line is not called in well over 20 log files being populated at run-time).  Am I misunderstanding how rufus works?  Please advise.  All I want to do is make sure that no more than 20 are running at once.

EDIT : Ruby version -- ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]
Rails version -- Rails 3.2.0

EDIT 2 : Here is something I've tried to insert at the beginning of the block :

```
if scheduler.running_jobs.length > MAX_CONCURRENT_STUFF_ALLOWED
  next
end
```

where MAX... is a positive integer.  This simply doesn't seem to have any effect.

Thanks!

Comment: Please expand your question by including the code you use to count "how many jobs are running". Max work thread sets a cap on the number of threads, not on the number of jobs. Also please indicate a) Ruby version b) Rails server (webrick, passenger, unicorn, ...). Without those pieces of information it's hard to help you.

Comment: So you just proved my point, I am misunderstanding Rufus.  There is no other code I use to count how many jobs are running, I thought setting max_work_threads was how I am supposed to enforce it.  I updated the question with ruby and rails versions, respectively.

Comment: Please answer my question b) as well, that's very important. Now, about your "Yet, as execution proceeds, I discover that more than 20 such jobs are running at any given time", how do you discover that?

Comment: There is no server "type" that I am aware of, all it says when I type "rails -v" is the version number.  As for how I know more jobs are running than I want, I have external logging (log4r) to show me that execution of sub-routines inside '# do stuff that may take 1 minute or 50 minutes' is still happening.  Don't know how to be any more clear without getting proprietary.  Updated question in any case.

Comment: When Rails start, it usually indicates in the first ten lines of its log what server it uses. Something like https://gist.github.com/jmettraux/fcdbecc22085ee0caa4d (where the server is Webrick).

Comment: Is your conditional in EDIT 2 triggering? A "next" has to be part of a for loop, a block is not a loop, thus I think your "if" never evaluates to true. (evaluating a next on its own: https://gist.github.com/jmettraux/24422a879f419f86a24e )

Comment: BTW, are you sure your logger flushes its buffer for each call to "log". It could be that the log messages are flushed well after the jobs are over...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in rufus-scheduler to set the max jobs, only the max threads.

You can determine how many work threads are currently employed by evaluating

```
scheduler.work_threads.size
```

If your max_work_threads is not respected, please fill a detailed issue report with reproduction steps at https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/issues

It might also help to log https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#schedulerrunning_jobs et al

I was trying hard to get you to tell me which server you are using because, some server implementations start multiple ruby processes and thus multiple schedulers and that might match your symptoms (locking help in those cases https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#lockfile--mylockfiletxt and its sibling paragraph).

> well over 20 log files being populated at run-time

Do you mean that each of your rufus-scheduler job gets its own log file? Usually there are one or two log files per OS process. Why this exceptional setup?

Thanks for communicating with precision, it saves time.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  So if I am unable to enforce any sort of maximum job count, then rufus-scheduler is not a viable solution for the implementation I am trying to achieve, correct?  Also, thanks for the direction on Rails server type, this is what is written :>> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop.  Does that mean "knife" or "thin" is what you were looking for?

Comment: Also to answer your other question, we do have a single master-Rails log for general info and error messages, but there is also a log file generated for each run-through of a job because the contents of a job represent a fairly compartmentalized transaction in our system.  Added an edit to main question to show what else I've tried.

Comment: I cannot answer "rufus-scheduler is not a viable solution for the implementation I am trying to achieve, correct?" because you are not proving squarely that rufus-scheduler is running more than 20 jobs at a time. If you could output scheduler.running_jobs / scheduler.work_threads in your logs and then show one of those logs ( https://gist.github.com ftw) then I could tell you "ok something is wrong" and then, eventually, "rufus-scheduler cannot do what you want". But for now, you are not showing anything with scheduler.running_jobs > 20

Comment: Yes, "Thin" is the answer to my question (What server does Rails run on). Thanks a lot! Thin does not, IIRC, fork new ruby processes, so, I think, you have a single scheduler running.